# Running Firefox on a remote Ubuntu server, controlling GUI locally from macOS

Tags: ssh, x11, firefox, gui

My local machine is a macbook running macOS, my remote machine is an Ubuntu 20.04 server with no display or GUI or desktop environment. I typically use this server only through ssh.

Now I want to run a GUI app (Firefox) on the remote server and somehow view and control the contents of the remote (virtual?) Firefox window on my own local machine.

Upon reading I understand this is supposed to be possible with something called X or X11, but despite some searching and experimenting I'm really not sure how this works or what I'm doing.

If I just run `firefox` on the remote machine in an ssh shell it says:

> Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified

If I connect to my server using `ssh -X rocketnuts@myserver` I notice upon logging in it says:

> Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated

And when I now run `firefox` it gives the same error, no DISPLAY environment variable specified.

If I locally do: `set DISPLAY=":0.0"; ssh -X rocketnuts@myserver` and then in the ssh shell on the remote machine I do: `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0`. If I now run `firefox` it says:

> Unable to init server: Broadway display type not supported: localhost:0.0
> Error: cannot open display: localhost:0.0

Having zero experience with X or remote GUI apps, I'm clueless as to what this even means. Assuming X is a protocol to view or control GUI apps that run somewhere remote, I'd say I need to use some kind of compatible client (is an 'X viewer/controller' a thing?) on my macbook and let that connect to the remote process.

I'm fairly sure this is possible but as you can see I lack some fundamental knowledge. Is there an easy way to set this up?

Comment: This is possible. You can refer to this tutorial for example. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apple-osx-mountain-lion-mavericks-install-xquartz-server/ You need to have xquartz installed on your Mac and X11 forwarding on the ubuntu server's ssh configuration. It's all in there

Comment: @Alex Thanks, I tried this and with `ssh -Y` I managed to get an X window with what seems to be a remotely running Firefox. However it is incredibly slow, as in when I click a tab or press a key it takes like a full minute to respond. I noticed that on the server shell, after starting `firefox` it says: `libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found` and `libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast`. Not sure what 'libGL' refers to but note that I'm not opening any websites containing WebGL or something. I just start Firefox with an empty tab.